# Opengl PBO is not improving the drawing speed

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am doing video streaming using opengl with the texture.
In order to improve the efficiency I tried the PBO method.

However I found that when I used the PBO

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, pboIds[pboturn]);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, cols, rows, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

and when I don't use PBO by just calling:

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, cols, rows, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mydata);
```

Though both are drawing the image, but the PBO one doesn't offer any efficiency improvement...
Is this because I am using a integrated intel HD4000 series video device but not any stand alone video card (It's actually a surface pro)?

And the glTexSubImage2D takes me about 10+ms for uploading a 1920*1080 rgb image. Is this normal? I am developing under Qt, is there anyohter way I could improve the performance?

**UPDATE:**
I have test the same program on a AMD graphic card. And the time consumed dropped under 1ms... Can I say it is the limit of the intel graphic device?

**UPDATE2:**

Here is the buffer generation and data uploading part:

```
glGenBuffers(1, pboIds);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboIds[0]);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, cols*rows*4, data, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

For testing, I only send the data one time during the initialization, so there is no more data uploading to the PBO also no buffer mapping in the testing code.

Comment: Maybe you can add some more of your map/unmap code?

Comment: Hi, for my testing case I only upload one picture one time through the glBufferData function and repeatedly display that single image... So it seems it is not the problem of the map/unmap code

Comment: @Nyaruko: well, if you do this in a loop without extra precautions or explicit orphaning, this might as well be an issue of the map/unmap code. From what you have shown so far, it is toatlly unclear what is going on, and what exactly it is that you are measuring.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. pls see update2.

Comment: Does this work correctly? You store 3 bytes per pixel in the buffer, but then use it as RGBA data, which is 4 bytes per pixel.

Answer (score 2):

If you just use PBOs as a in-sequence proxy for image uploads you'll gain nothing, since you're essentially I/O bound and have to wait for the data to be transferred. The idea behind PBOs is, that you can do data transfers and texture image specification "in the background", while the GPU is busy drawing stuff.

So to actually benefit from PBO-ed uploads you must make your program to operate asynchronously.

Comment: But according to the documentation, when I use PBO then during drawing, when I glBindBufferARB() first and glTexSubImage2D() should return in no time and the GPU will do all the rest?